# Random Letter C in Website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

http://www.iamaaron.com/beta/

If you view that page, there is a random amount of spacing at the top of the page, above the white header, that is not supposed to be there. If you will notice as well to the very top left of the screen there is the letter "C". I cannot figure out what is outputting this and how to make it go away. It's not even showing up in the DOM.

Any ideas?
Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`typicons.css:19`

```
.home:before {
    content: "C";
}
```

Comment: That makes sense. Had a brain fart. Thank you! I will accept your answer when I can.

Answer (score 2):

This "C" letter is in CSS file icons/css/typicons.css:

```
.home:before {
    content: "C";
}
```